# SSAS Show Details for a bridge measure incorrect

Tags: many-to-many, ssas, sql-server-2014

The bridge table provides for many-to-many between the two dimensions. The 'Breached flag' is in the bridge as that is it's context.

[image]

Dimension usage:

[image]

A measure exists for Fact_Ticket.Item and another for SLA_component_ticket_bridge.Breached Flag. They work just fine as cube values.

The problem is with Show Detail. For Fact_Ticket.Item it is OK but not for Breached Flag as it shows the same rows as Fact_Ticket.Item; so in effect it ignores the value of the flag when returning the atomic detail.

My feeling is that the dimension usage must change in some way.

Comment: Could you filter out the BreachedFlag=0 rows in SQL so SSAS never sees them. Are those rows needed in the bridge table for the many-to-many relationship?

Comment: I do require the rows for BreachedFlag=0. As the value of either 0 or 1 produces a sub-set of the rows in Fact_Ticket.Item ( just a simple row count measure ) it would not help anyhow.